# Calculate values between two numbers (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

If **15** is the lowest number and **200** the highest number, what formula do I need to use to define a multiplication pattern that applies the 28 values needed to complete this multiplication table?

> I would like to learn how to create this pattern to use, I tried it
> through percentages but I was not successful exactly because it had
> the minimum and the maximum, if it was only the minimum or only the
> maximum, just multiply it by the percentage.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to paste those values in the same column you need to do:

[image: 0]

then the formula will be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), )))+SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-2)), 1, 0)*(A1-INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))))/(
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-1))
```

[image]

---

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in A2 `=$A1+($A$30-$A$1)/29` and then drag down to A29